# Google analytics import chart how to sort date?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-analytics

I have registered a web in google analytics, and import its visitor data to the web. Using `gapi` library and google chart API I have successfully imported and visualized the data.

The problem is that: the chart is not sorted by date, it appears to random. 1st node is 20Feb and 2nd node suddenly jumps to 24Feb (next 25Feb,19,22,21, respectively), like shown in picture below:

[image]

[image]

The data is valid in google analytics itself:

[image]

Here's my code to draw the chart:

```
<?php
            require('tools/gapi/gapi.class.php');

            $ga = new gapi(ga_email, ga_password);
            $ga->requestReportData(ga_app_id, array('date', 'userDefinedValue'), array('pageviews', 'uniquePageviews', 'visits', 'visitors'));
            $results = $ga->getResults();
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Visits');

                data.addRows([
                    <?php
                        foreach($results as $result) {
                            echo '["'.date('M j',strtotime($result->getDate())).'", '.$result->getVisits().'],';
                        }
                    ?>
                ]);

                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                chart.draw(data, {width: 910, height: 250, title: '<?php echo date('M j, Y',strtotime('-30 day')).' - '.date('M j, Y'); ?>',
                    colors:['#058dc7','#e6f4fa'],
                    areaOpacity: 0.1,
                    hAxis: {textPosition: 'in', showTextEvery: 5, slantedText: false, textStyle: { color: '#058dc7', fontSize: 10 } },
                    pointSize: 5,
                    legend: 'none',
                    chartArea:{left:0,top:30,width:"100%",height:"100%"}
                });
            }
        </script>

        <div id="chart"></div>
        <div id="page-analytics">
            <div class="metric">Total page dikunjungi<br/><strong>{{ number_format($ga->getPageviews()) }}</strong></div>
            <div class="metric">Total page unik dikunjungi<br/><strong>{{ number_format($ga->getUniquePageviews()) }}</strong></div>
            <div class="metric">Total visit<br/><strong>{{ number_format($ga->getVisits()) }}</strong></div>
            <div class="metric">Total pengunjung<br/><strong>{{ number_format($ga->getVisitors()) }}</strong></div>
        </div>
```

Can anyone tell me what's the solution so the chart can be sorted by date? Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with highcharts?

Comment: actually no,  i just used all the tags stackoverflow auto generates, i will delete that

Answer (score 0):

That code is really old looks like no one has been developing on that project since 2009.  But  I did some digging around in the [gapi.class.php](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/source/browse/trunk/gapi.class.php)  I found a reference for something called metric sort.  This doesn't sound right to me, because the sort in the current version of GA API it doesn't matter if you sort on a dimension or a metric. I have no idea if this was something that the old API required. It looks like its an optional fourth value you can send to `requestReportData`

- @param String $report_id
- @param Array $dimensions Google Analytics dimensions e.g. array('browser')
- @param Array $metrics Google Analytics metrics e.g. array('pageviews')
- @param Array $sort_metric OPTIONAL: Dimension or dimensions to sort by e.g.('-visits')

I'm not sure how much help that is but i would like to sugest you use something more curent like: [Visualizing Google Analytics Data with Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts)